# What to set $DISPLAY environment variable to when su to another user

Tags: linux, redhat, x11, rhel8

I'm not that au fait with Linux, let alone things like X and display/window managers.

I am trying to run the GUI installer for Oracle Enterprise Manager, but it is complaining about the value for the DISPLAY environment variable, and is not able to load the GUI.

I am logging in as root then launching terminal, and can see the value for the variable is `hostname:0`. I need to run the installer as Oracle, so I `su - oracle` and then set the variable to the same value using `export DISPLAY=hostname:0`

I assume there is some kind of permission mechanism that prevents this from working, so I am wondering what I can do with the DISPLAY environment variable for Oracle, to allow the installer to run? Is it a case of having to log in as Oracle and launching the terminal directly, or can it be done after su'ing?

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure X11 authentication MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE.

You can use [xauth](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xauth) to configure it:

```
xauth list $DISPLAY # To list X11 cookies
sudo -iu oracle
# Import the cookies one by one
xauth add laptop.example.org/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  someHexString
```

Or alternatively:

```
xauth extract - $DISPLAY | ssh oracle@localhost xauth merge -
```

Or set `$XAUTHORITY` environment variable:

```
export XAUTHORITY=$(xauth info|grep "^Authority file"|awk '{print $3}')
sudo -iu oracle
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if there is a preferred approach when logging into the machine via the console session on RHEL 8?
In any case, I tried the first method and get error:
xauth timeout in locking authority file /run/user/0.mutter-Xwaylandauth

Comment: When do you see this error? After which command?

Comment: Sorry, this error is seen after running `xauth add laptop.example.org/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  someHexString` I did `xauth add hostname/unix:  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  HEX-Returned-from 'xauth list $DISPLAY as root'`

Comment: I found a suggestion to run `strace xauth list`. Doing this I can see entries that say `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/run/user/0/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.SD92F2-c", 0_WRONLY|0_CREAT|0_EXCL, 0600) = -1 EACCESS (Permission Denied)`. Should it not be trying to write to an xauthority file in the Oracle users' home directory?

Comment: you need to run `xauth list` as your GUI/normal user, not as root. User with UID 0 is root.

Comment: I can make an account for myself, but I am currently logging in and using terimanl via the GUI as root. Does it not work with root account?

Comment: I tried creating myself my own account and running via that, but get the same problem

Comment: How do you login? From the same machine from a remote one? What is the reported error? How do you test? You can also use `xlogo` to test if X11 works.

Comment: It's a VM, so I am logging into the GUI via the console session, then launching terminal. Error is as mentioned in previous comment, with permission error on file `"/run/user/0/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.SD92F2-c"`. The fact it's a GUI session I assume is enough confirmation that X11 is working?

Comment: Yes, it is. Can you start X11 applicaitons from the terminal? You can try with `xlogo`.

Comment: Running xlogo just gives me an unknown command message

Comment: It is part of `xlogo` package. You need to install it.